# Prove that $\lim_{x\to y} \frac{d(x, F )}{|x−y|} = 0$ for a.e. $y \in F$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a closed set and define the distance from $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to $F$ by $d(x,F)= \inf_{y \in F} |x−y|.$

Prove that

$$\lim_{x\to y} \frac{d(x, F )}{|x−y|} = 0$$ for a.e. $y \in F$.

Hint: Consider Lebesgue points of F.

I am not sure where to begin on this question.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the symbol in the denominator, before $|x - y|$?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Do you mean $d(x, F) / |x - y|$? I see an extraneous character there.

Comment: I guess.  It looks like that is what it says to me.  Maybe it looks different on my screen.

Comment: You can try editing what you think looks wrong to you.

Comment: This seems to relate to Lebesgue density theorem, since $F$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to obtain the result you seek is to appeal to Rademacher's Theorem since the distance function is $1$-Lipschitz and since this function attains its minimum at $y\in F$ the derivative can only be $0$. I suspect this is not available to you (just thought it might be interesting) so we proceed as follows:

If $x\in F$ then we have $\frac{d(x,F)}{\lvert x-y\rvert}=0$ so we only worry about $x\in F^{c}$. In this case we denote by $z_{x}\in F\cap[x,y]$ the closest point to $x$ in $[x,y]$ that belongs to $F$. Notice that it must be that $(x,z_{x})\subset F^{c}$ by the definition of $z_{x}$. So we have:

$0\le\frac{d(x,F)}{\lvert x-y\rvert}\le\frac{\lvert x-z_{x}\rvert}{\lvert x-y\rvert}=\frac{m((z_{x},x))}{\lvert x-y\rvert}\le\frac{m(F^{c}\cap(x,y))}{m((x,y))}\to0$.

if $y$ is a Lebesgue point of $F$. Thus, at Lebesgue points of $F$ the derivative exists and is $0$. Since almost every point is a Lebesgue point we conclude that the derivative exists almost everywhere.

Comment: The idea with Rademacher's Theorem is really neat. In dimension 1, that theorem could be available to the OP, as it more or less follows if you know about Lebesgue points and absolutely continuous functions, because Lipschitz functions are absolutely continuous, hence of the form $f(x) = \int_{x_0}^x f'(t) \,dt$ and thus a.e. differentiable by Lebegue's differentiation theorem.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Most likely OP knows all the material needed to be able to prove Rademacher's Theorem in this case.