# $F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, Then $\frac{d(x+y, F)}{|y|}\rightarrow 0, |y|\rightarrow 0$ for each $x\in F$.

Tags: real-analysis

$F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ and denote $d(y,F)=\inf\{|y-z|: z\in F\}.$ Then $$\frac{d(x+y, F)}{|y|}\rightarrow 0, |y|\rightarrow 0$$ for a.e $x\in F$.

I have no idea even though the hint says that the Lebesgue identity is useful.

Comment: This is **not** true for **each** $x \in F$, take e.g. $F = \{0 \}$. You can show (using the Lebesgue differentiation theorem) that it is true for almost all $x \in F$. Have a look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850601/prove-that-lim-x-to-y-fracdx-f-x%E2%88%92y-0-for-a-e-y-in-f/850651#comment1754149_850651 for a proof of the a.e. version. Also note the comments to the answer.

Comment: oh, sorry, someone has posted already, so I think I should delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Really? If $F=\{0\}$ and $x=0$ then $d(x+y,F)=|y|$ for every $y$.